# How to drop variables in two dataframes that they do not have in common in R?

Tags: r, variables, dataframe

I have two dataframes, one with 140 variables the other with 100. The first one has 40 extra variables that I do not want, otherwise the variables in the dataframes are the same. Now, I tried to drop the variables that are not the same by doing:

```
drop_var <- function(df1,df2) {             
  for (i in colnames(df1)) {                #for variable i in df1, if i is not in df2 then drop variable i. 
    if (!(i %in% colnames(df2))) {
      df1$i <- NULL
    }
  }
}
```

However, this doesn't work, nothing happens.

Comment: You can try `df1[names(df2)]`

Comment: @Sumedh Works exactly as I wanted it to! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
extraVars <- setdiff(names(df1), names(df2))
df1_test <- subset(df1, -extraVars)
```

Comment: This gives me the error `Error in -extraVars : invalid argument to unary operator`

Comment: Use `intersect(x, y)`, so `clean <- df1[,intersect(names(df1), names(df2))];`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Collect the variable you want to keep in an object, I would do this using base R.
ex:

```
df <- data.frame(a=rnorm(100),
                 b=rnorm(100),
                 c=rnorm(100),
                 d=rnorm(100),
                 e=rnorm(100),
                 f=rnorm(100),
                 g=rnorm(100))


df1<-as.matrix(as.character(names(df)))

drop<-as.vector(df1[c(1:3,5,6),])
```

Then simply keep the variables you want instead of dropping them

```
df3 <- subset(df, select = !(names(df) %in% c(drop)))
```

This should produce:

```
> head(df3)
           d          g
1 -1.3697508 -0.1414473
2  0.3404581  0.9168616
3 -0.9436178  0.2139926
4  0.3428353 -0.5360478
5 -0.3612498 -0.6443705
6  2.2175504 -0.8422576
```

From:

```
> head(df)
             a           b          c          d
4  -1.14816083 -2.27262219  1.7403998  0.3428353
7  -0.51135701  0.08747125  0.2614962 -1.4623207
11  0.32353664  0.40597367 -0.7161519  1.4011651
14 -1.19320503  0.33131922  0.4805208 -0.2811984
18 -0.08023675  0.82423082 -0.2184070  1.4679359
21 -0.42432261  0.46067636  0.5329394  0.6764477
             e           f           g
4  -0.51036700  1.01889198 -0.53604779
7   0.07670036 -0.89020788  1.60280134
11  1.55295828  0.08932072  0.16203588
14 -1.66679770  0.95550962  0.04557572
18 -0.53634264  0.63073156 -0.04173638
21  0.39662023  0.84527703 -0.18390707
```